# Search DialogViewController elements by clicking a button

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a `DialogViewController` with `EnableSearch = true`.

This works fine and filters the elements as soon I type something in the search box. What I would like to do was override this behavior and filter the elements only when the user pressed a button or StringElement.

I've looked at the StartSearch, FinishSearch and PerformFilter methods but don't see how they can be used to prevent the filtering as the user is typing.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. Looked at the code and the only virtual methods that can be overridden won't allow you to stop the reload of the tabledata. The PerformFilter should be overridden cause it's called by the delegate of the searchbar.

Comment: We figured that this was impossible to do with the DialogViewController and ended up using another control to perform the search "on demand". Thanks for the comment, @TimBrand :).